# Swift - How to wait until GPS returns correct coordinates

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-location

I am currently running into the issue of the GPS returning the coordinates 0,0 when I call the location when I first run it. If I call the same function again a second later it returns the correct values, so I think I just need to wait retrieve the coordinates until the GPS has "warmed up", but I am not sure how to do this.

This is the function I am calling:

```
func reload(){
        
        var coor = self.locationManager.location != nil ?
            self.locationManager.location!.coordinate :
            CLLocationCoordinate2D()

       //I send a http request using the gps data here
        ...
    }
}
```

I call this function on .onapear for the view, and it retrieves the correct data when debugging, but not when running standalone. I initialize the location manager with the other @state variables for the view.

Location manager:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
 
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation? = nil
    @Published var locationAllowed:Bool = true
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    ...
}
```

This is the general structure of the program:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
         View{
         }.onAppear(){
               Reload()
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in a sense that you need to wait for the GPS to "warm up" -- but, that will happen at an indeterminate time in the future.

You've left out quite a bit of code in your `LocationManager`, but presumably you have delegate methods there that update your `@Published` property `location`.

You should probably listen for changes on `location` and then call `reload()` if necessary (ie, the first call).

That might look *something* like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State private var hasLoaded = false
    
    var body: some View {
         VStack {
            Text("Hello, world")
         }.onReceive(locationManager.$location) { newLocation in
            if let newLocation = newLocation {
                reload(location: newLocation.coordinate)
            }
         }
    }
    
    func reload(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        guard hasLoaded == false else {
            return
        }
        hasLoaded = true
        //http request here
    }
}
```